# Ignoring specific symbols in referenced assemblies

Tags: assemblies, c++-cli, reference, redefinition

I have two managed assemblies that use a common batch of code. When referencing one to the other, the compiler complains about multiple redefinitions, as expected. Would it be possible to ignore the common symbols present in the referenced assembly during project compilation ? Or perhaps some other method/workaround to allow such a setup ?

Comment: Can you clarify/elaborate on how your common batch of code is being exported by both assemblies? Why can't one export it and the other consume it? Or, why can't the common code be made private so there are no conflicts?

Comment: Well, I merely want to confine sections of the code to the assemblies that they best belong to. In any case, I was able to get it to compile after change the appropriate access modifiers. Guess I needed some shut eye before I could work at optimal level. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per above comment, fixed by changing the common code's access modifiers to 'private'.